# Unwanted state changes in a class component with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Long story short, I have a class component that constructs a poll. Before sending the data to the server I need to transform it a little so it fits the API request. I created a `transformData` method on my class component that transforms the data derived from the state. As a side effect it sets the data in separate `this.state.data` property so I can attach it with the API request. The problem is that the method mutates the other properties of the state.

```js
transformData = () => {
    const { title, sections } = this.state

    const transformedSections = sections.map(section => {
      delete section.isOpen
      const transformedQuestions = section.questions.map(question => {
        question.label = question.question
        question.type = toUpper(question.type)
        delete question.question
        return question
      })
      section.questions = {
        create: transformedQuestions,
      }
      return section
    })

    this.setState({
      data: {
        title,
        sections: { create: transformedSections },
      },
    })
  }
```

So I get this:

```js
state: {
  data: {...} //our transformed data
  sections: {...} //transformed as well!!
}
```

instead of getting this:

```js
state: {
  data: {...} //our transformed data
  sections: {...} //same before calling the method
```

I re-wrote the method with different approach — basically replaced all `Array.map` with `Array.forEach` and it worked as expected.

```js
transformData = () => {
    const { title, sections } = this.state

    const transformedSections = []

    sections.forEach(section => {
      const transformedQuestions = []
      section.questions.forEach(question => {
        transformedQuestions.push({
          label: question.question,
          type: toUpper(question.type),
          max: question.max,
          min: question.min,
          instruction: question.instruction,
          isRequired: question.isRequired,
          placeholder: question.placeholder,
        })
      })

      transformedSections.push({
        title: section.title,
        questions: { create: transformedQuestions },
      })
    })

    this.setState({
      data: {
        title,
        sections: { create: transformedSections },
      },
    })
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? How can I accidentally mutate a state property without explicitly calling `this.setState` on the aforementioned property? The thing is that the originally written method mutates the state even if I return the data object without calling `this.setState` whatsoever. Like so:

```js
//This still mutates the state
return { 
  data: {
        title,
        sections: { create: transformedSections },
      }
}

//without this!

//this.setState({
    //   data: {
    //     title,
    //     sections: { create: transformedSections },
    //   },
    // })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript behave like this way,
its called variable referencing.
it works like pointer variable in C.

if your console those variable such as `console.log(var1 == var2)` it will show true cuz both references from same memory location

if you want to prevent mutate original variable then you have to create another brand new variable to mutate

like this way :

```
const { title, sections } = this.state

// create new variable following old one (spreading es6 way)
const tempSections = [...sections]
...
```

also

```
sections.forEach(section => {
      const transformedQuestions = []
      const tempQuestions = [...section.questions]
      tempQuestions.forEach(question => {
      ...
```

**always have to create a brand new variable of object/array/... to prevent auto mutation**

for further info [here](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is of **[Shallow Copying](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript#toc-shallow-copying-objects)** :

```
    console.log("---- before map -----" , this.state);
    const { title, sections } = this.state

    // sections is another object, and via map you are mutating inner objects
    // beacuse of the shallow Copying

    const transformedSections = sections.map(section => {
      // any change on section object will direct mutate state
      delete section.isOpen //<--- Here you are mutating state
      return section
    })
    // state is muate already
    console.log("---- After map -----" , this.state);
```

---

You can run the below code snippet and check both `console.log`, and check for `"isOpen": true`

Hope this will clear all your doubts :

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
      title : "questions" ,
      sections : [{
        isOpen : true ,
        questions : ["que1" , "que2" , "que3"]
      }]
  }

  transfromData = () => {
    
    console.log("---- before map -----" , this.state);
    const { title, sections } = this.state

    // sections is another object, and via map you are mutating inner objects
    // beacuse of the shallow Copying

    const transformedSections = sections.map(section => {
      // any change on section object will direct mutate state
      delete section.isOpen //<--- Here you are mutating state
      return section
    })
    console.log("---- After map -----" , this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.transfromData}>transfromData</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never update the state without using the `setState` method. It is asyncronous, and if you don't set it properly you never know what might happen - and that's what you're seeing in the first part of your answer. See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

By doing

```
section.questions = {
        create: transformedQuestions,
      }
```

you are improperly altering the state, so you'll see `this.state.sections` transformed as well, because each element inside `this.state.sections` has now an attribute `questions` that contains `create` with the value `transformedQuestions`